# Send HUGE e-mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send an e-mail using the Java mail API. But my e-mail text is to big to be stored on a String.

Is there any way to send an e-mail with something like a String array, or any Collection?

Comment: You can store up to 2 GB in a String. Are you sure your email server can handle emails this big?

Comment: Well , I basically save a log that for now has like... 1k lines of log. But in the future it might bring something as big as 10k or more. I think I'll just try to send it as an attachment. But tyvm for the help

Comment: How long does it take to read a 2GB email?

Comment: Maybe you should compress the log file and then attach it to the email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to send an attachment?  If so, rather than composing the message yourself, the attachment example in this link may be useful:
http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html#SendingAttachments

Comment: Seeing your comment above, I'd definitely recommend sending log files as an attachment if you expect them to be very large.

Comment: They'll be .txt files. So that may be the right option. It'd be a lot harder to read this on an e-mail and to manage the String size (As commented by @PeterLawrey), as well.